# Connecting ionic to mysql db

Tags: mysql, ionic-framework, backand

I have a web app designed on laravel and an ionic app. Mysql db was connected with the laravel app and I want to connect the ionic app with the same db aswell. Please tell me whats the best way to do this. 
P.S I'm currently trying to work out a solution using back& but can't understand how to make the connection. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ionic is a web application. The best way to connect an ionic app with DB/Back end is by using RestFul web services.
You can look for "how to create a RestFul server using laravel"

After you set up a RestFul server you are good to go. If your app requires authentication then you will have to create api keys or some id that you would send in the authorization header when you hit an endpoint in the RestFul apis

Answer (score 0):

Re: your postscript: Connecting a MySQL database to Back& can be done as follows:

1. Log into the Back& Dashboard at www.backand.com
2. Navigate to
   your app's management dashboard by finding the correct tile and
   clicking "Manage my App"
3. Access the database settings in
   "Settings -> Database"
4. Click on "Connect my Database"
5. Select "MySQL"
6. Add all of the required information for your database server (endpoint, database name, username, password)
7. Click "Connect"

Back& will then rebuild your object structure and connect its data grids to your existing database.